# Limited Connection - Network Issue

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, dell-poweredge, broadcom

I'm having issues with a Windows Server 2012 - Dell PowerEdge R300.

Every time the server restarts the network adapter gets limited connection and does not work. I have to locally disable the network adapter and re-enable and it works normally until the next reboot.

Network Adapter: Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet
Driver version: 16.6.0.4 - specifically from Broadcom Website since Dell Support is with 16.2.0 and the issue still happening.

After the issue I look into the Event viewer however does not show me anything useful.

Any ideas what could be causing it ?

Comment: `1.` Have you checked for a firmware update for the NIC? `2.` What other diagnostics/troubleshooting have you performed? `3.` Have you verified DNS settings and the default gateway settings? `4.` Can you manually run these tests successfully? - http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2012/12/20/the-network-connection-status-icon.aspx

Comment: Are you statically assigning an IP Address? Typically you do not use dynamic addressing for servers.

Comment: I ran into this same issue at my last job with a PowerEdge... I've completely forgotten the fix.  I'm so sorry.  I'm thinking it was something dumb like disable IPv6 (if you don't need it), but am not sure.  You could start there.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem with Dell servers. Go into the system (hardware) setup and look for a conflicting network adapter assignment such as Static with a useless default IP address. If you wish to continue assigning a dynamic IP address to that NIC, make sure the BIOS is configured for the same at boot-up.